# Indicate when room is in timeout by a different background color

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-timeout

When a chat room is frozen or deleted, it means ordinary users can't post messages, and we see those rooms with a gray background in the rooms list.

However, currently there is no special background when a room is in timeout, but ordinary users still can't post. They find out only when entering the room.

Can rooms in timeout get a different background please? My suggestion is lighter version of frozen or deleted rooms, e.g.:

[image]

Comment: Timeouts seems like a short term thing, so not sure if it is needed.

Comment: @ber it can be a full day, not that short... :-)